# How to handle django import-export 'matching query does not exist.' error?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am using import-export library and trying to add import functionality in admin panel.

Resource:

```
class DictCitizen_FisResources(resources.ModelResource):
id = fields.Field(
    column_name='№',
    attribute='id',
)
country_name = fields.Field(
    column_name='Name',
    attribute='dict_citizen',
    widget=ForeignKeyWidget(DictCitizen, field='sname')
)
fis_id = fields.Field(
    column_name='Element Code',
    attribute='fis_id',
)

class Meta:
    model = DictCitizen_Fis
    fields = ('id','country_name', 'fis_id',)
    import_id_fields = ('id',)
```

As u can see, one of the fields in **ResourceClass** (country_name) has **ForeignKeyWidget**, which means that when importing data from file - model relation is going to be created.
The problem is that, information in the file that i import from, does not always matches ForeignKeyWidget model data that is already in database and as a result i get next errors when trying to imoprt from admin panel:

[image: error text]

Same error written as a text:

> Номер строки: 25 - DictCitizen matching query does not exist. 25,
> БОЛИВИЯ, 238 Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line
> 737, in import_row self.import_obj(instance, row, dry_run, **kwargs)
> File "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py",
> line 557, in import_obj self.import_field(field, obj, data, **kwargs)
> File "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py",
> line 540, in import_field field.save(obj, data, is_m2m, **kwargs) File
> "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\fields.py", line 119,
> in save cleaned = self.clean(data, **kwargs) File
> "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\fields.py", line 75, in
> clean value = self.widget.clean(value, row=data, **kwargs) File
> "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\widgets.py", line 423,
> in clean return self.get_queryset(value, row,
> **kwargs).get(**{self.field: val}) File "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 496,
> in get raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
> dicts.models.base.DictCitizen.DoesNotExist: DictCitizen matching query
> does not exist

.

> Номер строки: 36 - DictCitizen matching query does not exist. 36,
> ВЕНЕСУЭЛА, 228 Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line
> 737, in import_row self.import_obj(instance, row, dry_run, **kwargs)
> File "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py",
> line 557, in import_obj self.import_field(field, obj, data, **kwargs)
> File "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py",
> line 540, in import_field field.save(obj, data, is_m2m, **kwargs) File
> "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\fields.py", line 119,
> in save cleaned = self.clean(data, **kwargs) File
> "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\fields.py", line 75, in
> clean value = self.widget.clean(value, row=data, **kwargs) File
> "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\import_export\widgets.py", line 423,
> in clean return self.get_queryset(value, row,
> **kwargs).get(**{self.field: val}) File "C:\venvs\abit\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 496,
> in get raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
> dicts.models.base.DictCitizen.DoesNotExist: DictCitizen matching query
> does not exist.

Because there are certain rows in the file, that contain information that does not match related model data, none of the rows are getting imported and i get error.

I would like to know how can i handle this kind of exeptions in the way so that all the matching row instances would be saved (imoprted) in database, and i could log the information about those that cannot be saved since related model cannot be found due to the DoesNotExist exeption.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to create a subclass of `ForeignKeyWidget` which ignores any failures (or you can log them or whatever):

```py
class PermissiveForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyWidget):

    def clean(self, value, row=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().clean(value)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            logger.warning(f"instance matching '{value}' does not exist")
```

Then declare this in your resource:

```py
country_name = fields.Field(
    column_name='Name',
    attribute='dict_citizen',
    widget=PermissiveForeignKeyWidget(DictCitizen, field='sname')
)
```